# Heavyweight Jquery slideshows are slow in desktops and crash on ipad 2, android ics and iphone

Tags: jquery, memory, crash, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I am building my portfolio site (have a look here ...)

http://www.tripleagent.co.uk/projects.html

And I am using Jquery with jquery.cycle.all.js.  I added about 200 slides with my work dated many years back and a few vimeo videos with fitvid.js (it resizes the videos to fit in a responsive design). My problem is that the page is slow on a workstation computer (i7 ivy bridge and chrome) and it crashes on ipad, android and iphone. I am new on jscript and html5 so I am not sure what is going wrong.

With my limited experience I believe that its running out of memory or that the slower machines can't handle the fade animations simultaneously.
I use a typical setup for the slideshow

```
$("#slideshow").cycle({
    fx:'fade,',
    speed: 1000,
    slideExpr:'.slide',
    slideResize: 0,
    timeout:        7000,
    pause: 1,
    //sync: true,
    autostop: false,
    pager: '#nav',
    next: '#slideshow',
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
    fastOnEvent: true ,         
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) 
    {return '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+slide.src + '"/></a></li>';
    },   
    after:   captionsAlt ,
    });
```

What should I do ? I can break up the page in two and it will probably work but i was thinking that there must be a way to optimize the page instead. 
Any suggestions? Is there any mistake, a bug or a bad design idea in the first place ?

Comment: Is there any online material to read further on how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

It has been months since i asked this question.

I upgraded to the latest jquery 1.9.1, cycle.all 3.0.4 I just noticed that Safari, IE9 and mozilla don't have  much of a problem anymore. The videos play well in android 4.1+ and IOS  but it is still a bit heavy and it has some problems regarding touching and scrolling on top of the vimeo player. but i asked that already in the vimeo forums.

Comment: Thanks for the information from the first part of the answer. As for the second part: please, create a new question with link to this one. A new question inside your answer is unlikely to be answered.